# using sentiwordnet for calculating polarity

Tags: java, semantics

Has someone worked with sentiwordnet. I keep getting the error `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2` when the sentiwordnet file is split which I downloaded from this site http://sentiwordnet.isti.cnr.it/ . I suppose I have to format the sentiwordnet file before using it. But how?

This is the program

```
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.Vector;

public class SWN3 {
    private String pathToSWN = "data"+File.separator+"SentiWordNet_3.0.0.txt";
    private HashMap<String, String> _dict;

    public SWN3(){

        _dict = new HashMap<String, String>();
        HashMap<String, Vector<Double>> _temp = new HashMap<String, Vector<Double>>();
        try{
            BufferedReader csv =  new BufferedReader(new FileReader(pathToSWN));
            String line = "";           
            while((line = csv.readLine()) != null)
            {
                String[] data = line.split("\t");
                Double score = Double.parseDouble(data[2])-Double.parseDouble(data[3]);
                String[] words = data[4].split(" ");
                for(String w:words)
                {
                    String[] w_n = w.split("#");
                    w_n[0] += "#"+data[0];
                    int index = Integer.parseInt(w_n[1])-1;
                    if(_temp.containsKey(w_n[0]))
                    {
                        Vector<Double> v = _temp.get(w_n[0]);
                        if(index>v.size())
                            for(int i = v.size();i<index; i++)
                                v.add(0.0);
                        v.add(index, score);
                        _temp.put(w_n[0], v);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Vector<Double> v = new Vector<Double>();
                        for(int i = 0;i<index; i++)
                            v.add(0.0);
                        v.add(index, score);
                        _temp.put(w_n[0], v);
                    }
                }
            }
            Set<String> temp = _temp.keySet();
            for (Iterator<String> iterator = temp.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
                String word = (String) iterator.next();
                Vector<Double> v = _temp.get(word);
                double score = 0.0;
                double sum = 0.0;
                for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
                    score += ((double)1/(double)(i+1))*v.get(i);
                for(int i = 1; i<=v.size(); i++)
                    sum += (double)1/(double)i;
                score /= sum;
                String sent = "";               
                if(score>=0.75)
                    sent = "strong_positive";
                else
                if(score > 0.25 && score<=0.5)
                    sent = "positive";
                else
                if(score > 0 && score>=0.25)
                    sent = "weak_positive";
                else
                if(score < 0 && score>=-0.25)
                    sent = "weak_negative";
                else
                if(score < -0.25 && score>=-0.5)
                    sent = "negative";
                else
                if(score<=-0.75)
                    sent = "strong_negative";
                _dict.put(word, sent);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}        
    }

    public String extract(String word, String pos)
    {
        return _dict.get(word+"#"+pos);
    }
}
```

Comment: The URL you included does not point to any resource.

Comment: Check what is the data returned here - String[] data = line.split("\t");

Comment: Ok, I see that your URL has included the start of the next sentence.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source file, there are a lot of headers that should be read and discarded before the actual data records are read.

Try discarding any line that starts with "#".

Comment: the readline() method returns a line such as 
a 00037457 0.375 0.5 active#1 tending to become more severe or wider in scope; "active 

tuberculosis" but sometimes the line returned is an empty string eventhough there is some text. how do i tackle this

Comment: BufferedReader.readLine() always returns up to the next LF, CR or CRLF. So if it is returning an empty string, that's because there was an empty line. Discard it and carry on.

Comment: At each split, you should probably check that something useful was returned. That way if you read something that doesn't meet your parsing requirements, you can handle it gracefully.